# How to dynamically create Deployment s3 bucket using AWS SAM CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I'm running `sam deploy`, by default it creates a deployment s3 bucket to save the built artifacts. you see it in the output of the command above in your terminal as:

> Managed S3 bucket: aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-1a4x26zbcdkqr
> A different default S3 bucket can be set in samconfig.toml and auto resolution of buckets turned off by setting resolve_s3=False

but I don't know how to override this behavior. meaning that configuring SAM CLI via `samconfig.toml` and tell it that creates a s3 bucket with provided name when it doesn't exist.
Im using `SAM CLI, version 1.81.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sam deploy --s3-bucket "YOUR S3 BUCKET"
```

More information here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html